# Mongoose aggregate match and addfield with provided list index

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to update the document's field order based on the index of the array I passed in. But when I call this API, the end result is [], and no expected changes in the database. Need your pieces of advice

the arrayI passed in is:

> ["5c1b9f2b66922a77ec7116a1", "5c1b9d4a66922b77ec81169f"]

```
exports.update_item_order = (req, res, next) => {
      const idList = req.body.idList;
      if (!idList) {
        res.status(400).json({
          message: "Missing request paramaters"
        });
      }
      vouchers.aggregate([{
        "$match": {
          "_id": {
            "$in": idList
          }
        }
      }, {
        "$addFields": {
          "order": {
            "$indexOfArray": [idList, "$_id"]
          }
        }
      }, {
        "$sort": {
          "order": 1
        }
      }]).exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json();
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Status update successfully',
          result
        })
      })
    };
```

Sample collection I am retrieving from

[image]

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869651/find-using-id-not-working-with-aggregation

Comment: Thank you very much, now I am able to use the $match, I am still trying to figure out how to use $in, since mongoose cant cast string to objectId automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the `ids` array and convert them to mongoose `ObjectId`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const ids = ["5c1b9f2b66922a77ec7116a1", "5c1b9d4a66922b77ec81169f"].map(id => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id))

vouchers.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": ids }}},
  { "$addFields": {
    "order": {
      "$indexOfArray": [ids, "$_id"]
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "order": 1 }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your method, It works nicely,  I am now figuring the rest on how to assign array index to the database fields :) I will upvote it since it solves part of it :) thanks

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I have a question on MongoDB aggregation and mongoose aggregation, do they all share the same keywords like $addFields or $addToSet, because I cannot seem to find any documentation on mongoose which state they support these keywords.

Comment: Mongoose is an object modelling tool for the mongodb. Mongoose has same queries and functions as of mongodb. You can refer  mongoose docs  [here](https://mongoosejs.com/). Nothing much difference as compared to mongodb

Comment: Thanks, You have saved my day. I saw my result, and the fields are assigned correctly. but after I refresh my MongoDB, my documents don't have the field 'order' there. but I will mark this as the answer since is solve the query. :) thanks

btw, I manage to get your code working, after removing the double quote from every "$xxx" keyword. maybe you can update it, so others can get the correct one